# Reverse words in a sentence with space complexity o(1)

Tags: javascript, string

I got one question: to reverse the words in a sentence. e.g. the original string is `Mike loves music`, after conversion, it should be `music loves Mike`;

my approach is simple:

```
const reverse = (str: string) =>  str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
```

the space complexity is `o(n)`

However, the follow up question is how to convert it with space complexity `o(1)`.

I am thinking to use two pointers, but seems too complex. Please advise.

Comment: `reverse()` works like this: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.reverse

Comment: hi @szab.kel I don't get your point. do you mean I didn't use reverse correctly? thanks

Comment: @szab.kel Step 1 is to create a second string object which has the same content as the original one - thus the space complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: @BenLi No, maybe you can get an idea for a different solution of something by looking at it.

Answer (score -4):

Simply

"yourText".split("").reverse().join("");

Comment: This is not `O(1)` space complexity.